# parts of my php code is displayed in browser

Tags: php, encoding

My php code is being displayed in the browser but only after the first echo is called leaving this output in the browser

> ";
>   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
>   echo " ".$row['title']; } echo ""; ?>

```
    <?php
require('settings.php');
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $mysql=mysql_connect(mysql_host, mysql_username, mysql_password, true);
        mysql_select_db(mysql_database, $mysql);
        $mostrecent=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC", $mysql);
        $top20=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table", $mysql);
        mysql_close($mysql);
        echo "<div id=\"mostrecent\">";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            echo "<br />".$row['title'];
        }
        echo "</div>";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

That is my code and those are constants defined in settings.php using `define()`.

Comment: In that case, your PHP is not being interpreted, most likely due to a server configuration issue.

Comment: Do you mind posting your code? It would help us find out the exact problem.

Comment: @Pekka which part of the configuration should I look at?
@Rakesh that is my code and the top part is what the browser displays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ENCODING ERROR, WAS UTF-16 on a server that didn't support UTF-16, re encoded into UTF-8 works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You're echoing your divs wrong. Try this:

```
echo '<div id="mostrecent">';
```

Do that on all your HTML echoes. Single quotes outside, double quotes inside.

Comment: That should not be the problem. The `\\` performs good at my site.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly have a quote issue.  Check that you are ending a quote with a " character and not some oddball unicode character that looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
"; while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results,MYSQL_ASSOC)){ echo "
".$row['title']; } echo ""; ?>
```

The above statement doesnot have `<?`.

Comment: You cannot tell that from the code the user pasted - he most likely copied it from the browser view instead of the source view.

Comment: that is the part that is outputed by the browser
@thiefmaster that is code from the source view

Answer (score 0):

chances are you have missed a (double quote) " or a (single quote) somewhere, and it is interpretting the rest of your code as text.

if it were a server configuration issue, none of your php would have been interpretted